# Search for tags in the future

Tags: org-agenda, org-tags

I would like to create a custom agenda view for future entries with a given tag (e.g. LABEL). I've tried something like:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("l" tags "+LABEL +TIMESTAMP >= \"<now>\"")))
```

but it still display tagged entries from the past. What would be the right query?
**Note** It's really for tags, not todo-tags, scheduled or deadlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the spaces. Try `"+LABEL+TIMESTAMP>=\"<now>\""`. And of course make sure that the entries you are interested in contain `LABEL` as a tag and also contain a "bare" timestamp:

```
* New Year                                                        :resolution:
  <2022-01-01>
  I resolve to get organized
```

Assuming the entry is in one of your agenda files, it should be found with

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("t" "future resolutions"
           tags "+resolution+TIMESTAMP>=\"<now>\"")))
```

The space is a boolean `OR` operator - see the section "Matching tags and properties" in the manual, which you can get to with `C-h i g (org)matching tags and properties`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where is the official documentation for the TIMESTAMP label? I had a hard time finding it (mostly browsing stack overflow)

Comment: If you go to the section of the manual I pointed to above, you can follow the link that says "Special properties". It describes all the special properties (including `TIMESTAMP`) that you can use in the matching string for org agenda custom commands. To go directly, use  `C-h i g(org)Special properties`.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the link. Still in this part of documentaton, I did not find the TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Here's the [Special properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties) section in the online Org manual. And for good measure, here's the [Matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties) section.